# How to remove blank elements from an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, c-strings, is-empty

I was working on file inputs. I wanted to store each line as a string in array. For example: if the file has lines:

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
```

The string should contain:

```
char str[][] = {"This is line 1.", "This is line 2.", "This is line 3."};
```

When I was trying out with extra spaces:

```
This is line 1.


This is line 2.
This is line 3.
```

The output was in the same format.
I want to delete those extra empty lines from my array of sentences, so that the output is same as before. How should I do that?

[EDIT] I am using following loop to enter sentences from file to the array:

```
while (fgets(str[i], LINE_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
{
    str[i][strlen(str[i]) - 1] = '\0';
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Show how you are entering strings.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I have edited the question.

Comment: regarding: `str[i][strlen(str[i]) - 1] = '\0';`  This is very IFFY,  Suggest: `str[i][ strcspn( str[i], "\n" ) ] = '\0';`  as that will always do the right thing (I.E. replacing a newline with a NUL byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an intermediate one-dimensional character array in the call of `fgets` like for example

```
for ( char line[LINE_SIZE]; fgets( line, LINE_SIZE, fp) != NULL; )
{
    if ( line[0] != '\n' )
    { 
        line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
        strcpy( str[i++], line );
    }
}
```

If a line can contain blanks you can change the condition of the if statement the following way

```
for ( char line[LINE_SIZE]; fgets( line, LINE_SIZE, fp) != NULL; )
{
    size_t n = strspn( line, " \t" );

    if ( line[n] != '\n' && line[n] != '\0' )
    { 
        line[ n + strcspn( line + n, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
        strcpy( str[i++], line );
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet you can substitute this statement

```
strcpy( str[i++], line );
```

for this statement if you want that the string would not contain leading spaces.

```
strcpy( str[i++], line + n );
```

Comment: If there are two "\n" after first line, one "\n" still remains.

Comment: @Srijan And what? It will be an empty string.

Comment: The output should be `This is line 1.\n This is line 2.\n This is line 3.`
Whereas the output is: `This is line 1.\n\n This is line 2.\n This is line 3.`

Comment: @Srijan Did you try the loop I showed? The lines do not contain the new line character. Where did you get them from?

Comment: Yes I tried your loop. When I am using the loop to print each string stored in the array, I am getting an extra blank line.

Comment: @Srijan It seems that the line is not empty and contain spaces. Insert after this statement line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0'; a check printf( "\"%s\"\n", line );

Comment: Yes there is a space. Just checked.
Out of curiosity, is there any way to keep that space in the original file but not in the array?

Comment: Thank you for your help.